# Visual Studio Source Control Explorer Duplicate TFS Project Folders

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, source-control-explorer

[image]Thought I saw this question answered somewhere on SO but I can't find it. My solution is properly displayed with its projects in Source Control Explorer, check ins are properly logged and the solution is mapped to my local workspace. (GREEN box)

However *below* the solution folder all the project folders are displayed again.The local path is not mapped and no check ins are being displayed. This is merely annoying to me but might seriously confuse my team. An hour of searching has turned up no solutions for getting rid of these ghost folders. (RED box)

Comment: "However below the solution folder all the project folders are displayed again" do you have screen shot? I can't imagine what you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No local path mapped to these folders indicates that these folders are no longer exist on the machine.

You can correct it via going to Source Control Explorer -> select these missing files -> **Undo Pending Changes**.

Comment: Thanks Vicky for getting my day off to a great start. Ten second fix.